# Why does it cause a run-time error, character to int without initializing?

Tags: c++

First of all, I apologize about poor english.

At next simple program,

```
void fx(int *a){
    for(int i=*a; i<='Z'; i++)
    printf("%c", i);
}
int main(){
    int a;
    scanf("%c", &a);
    fx(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

I entered a capital letter at run-time, it caused FATAL error and was solved by killing proccess.

It does not cause any problem at next codes.

```
//except fx()
int main(){
    int a;
    scanf("%c", &a);
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
//initialize int a
void fx(int *a){
    for(int i=*a; i<='Z'; i++)
    printf("%c", i);
}
int main(){
    **int a = 0;**
    scanf("%c", &a);
    fx(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

I know it should be 'char' to input character. but I cannot understand about above situation.

What happened?

PS. I worked with VS2010, c++

Comment: Just wondering, why are you using an `int` to input a character. Why not `char`? Heck, if it's tagged C++, why not `cin`?

Comment: >>Chris
I was just testing for something.
And I tagged because I used cpp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared an uninitialized int ***a***, and set it's lower-most byte to something. The result may be a very large number, because the upper-most bytes (whether 16bit or 32bit integers) were left unassigned/uninitialized.

When you passed it to the function, this one will use the full extent of the int **a** representation. You've then setup a cycle, with stop condition "till it gets to 'Z'", which, by the way, will be correctly promoted to an integer (i.e. all upper-most non-used bytes as 0).

In that cycle you'll be forcing poor printf to try output a byte spanning from 0 to 0xff, several gazillion of times, depending on how long it may take the ***i*** to rollover into 'Z'... apparently somewhere in that printf code, someone didn't like non-printable (not just non-ascii) codes.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I think this is more understandable for me.
The problem was **for loop** from 'dummy int a' to 'Z'.

Answer (score 8):

The difference between this

```
int a;
scanf("%c", &a);
```

and this

```
int a = 0;
scanf("%c", &a);
```

is that `int a;` declares an uninitialized `a`. So it can be anything. When you write

```
scanf("%c", &a);
```

on an uninitialized `int`, you're only setting the topmost bits, because `%c` tells `scanf` to write the input to a `char`, so only the first byte will be written. This can lead to some weird behavior, include what you just stated.

Comment: To add onto this, the reason this happens is `scanf` doesn't know how big the variable you're passing it is, (because you're passing a pointer to a memory address, not an `int` or `char` or whatever.)

Comment: Don't forget endianness issues: the first 8 bits of `a` may not represent the least significant ones...

Comment: Thank you for asnwer. Now Im understanding that 'scanf("%c")' to 'int' writes just one bite.